# Intermediate node not forwading all received packet during routing

Tags: unetstack

I want to send packets from source node 3 to the sink node 1, through intermediate node 2. Accordingly next-hop is configured in simulation script. Data packets are sent from source node 3 for every 2000 ms (2 seconds), for a duration of 2 minutes. Node 3 send 58 packets and all packets successfully received by node 2. But, Node 2 is forwarding only 4 packets to node 1 and we are not able to find packet forwarding entry of remaining packets.

Kindly tell me, why node 2 is not forwarding all received packets and how we can overcome this issue.

For same topology, when node 3 is sending packets for every 10000 ms (10 seconds), all packets are received and forwarded by intermediate node 2. Also all packets are received at sink node 1.

Simulation script:

```
//! Simulation:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// To run simulation:
///   collision study
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.phy.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.*
import static org.arl.unet.Services.*
import static org.arl.unet.phy.Physical.*
import org.arl.unet.net.*
import org.arl.unet.DatagramReq
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.*

channel.model = ProtocolChannelModel;
platform = org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform;

channel.soundSpeed = 1500.mps           // c
channel.communicationRange = 100.m     // Rc
channel.detectionRange = 125.m         // Rd
channel.interferenceRange = 150.m      // Ri
channel.pDetection = 1                  // pd
channel.pDecoding = 1                   // pc

modem.dataRate = [600.bps, 7200.bps]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

println '''
Node 1, 2, 3
sink: 1
Intermediate node: 2
Source: 3
'''
def packet_interval = 2000
simulate  2.minutes, {

  def n1 = node '1', remote: 1101, address: 1, location: [ 0.m, 0.m, 0.m], shell: true, stack:"$home/etc/initrc-stack"

  def n2 =  node '2', remote: 1102, address: 2, location: [ 0.m, 0.m, -90.m], shell: 5102, stack: "$home/etc/initrc-stack" 
      n2.startup = {        
        def router = agentForService Services.ROUTING       
        router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 1, nextHop: 1, reliability: false)             
      }

  def n3 =  node '3', remote: 1103, address: 3, location: [0.m, 0.m, -150.m], shell: 5103, stack: "$home/etc/initrc-stack"
   n3.startup = {        
        def router = agentForService Services.ROUTING
        router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: 1, nextHop: 2, reliability: false)
           add new TickerBehavior(packet_interval, {              
            router << new DatagramReq(to: 1, data:[1,2,3,4]) 
          })              
      }
    }
```

trace.nam:

```
# BEGIN SIMULATION 1
n -t 1566278862.018000 -s 3 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z -150.000000 -a 3
+ -t 1566278862.022000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1510346961 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
n -t 1566278862.025000 -s 1 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z 0.000000 -a 1
n -t 1566278862.028000 -s 2 -x 0.000000 -y 0.000000 -Z -90.000000 -a 2
- -t 1566278862.078000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1510346961 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278862.178000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1510346961 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278862.313000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1510346961 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278862.406000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1469617069 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278862.458000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1469617069 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278862.672000 -s 2 -d 3 -i 1469617069 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278862.692000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1469617069 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278863.958000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 20584737 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278864.014000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 20584737 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278864.114000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 20584737 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278864.226000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 20584737 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278864.514000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1477872544 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278864.566000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1477872544 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278864.780000 -s 2 -d 3 -i 1477872544 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278864.799000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1477872544 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278867.766000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 338049703 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278867.818000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 338049703 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278867.919000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 338049703 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278868.031000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 338049703 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278870.132000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -1449690937 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278870.188000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -1449690937 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278870.401000 -s 2 -d 3 -i -1449690937 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278870.421000 -s 2 -d 1 -i -1449690937 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278870.440000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 978676095 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278870.492000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 978676095 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278870.592000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 978676095 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278870.706000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 978676095 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278871.579000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1601755918 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278871.631000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1601755918 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278871.844000 -s 2 -d 3 -i 1601755918 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
r -t 1566278871.865000 -s 2 -d 1 -i 1601755918 -p 1 -x {2.0 1.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278872.338000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 956833424 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278872.393000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 956833424 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278872.493000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 956833424 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278872.606000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 956833424 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278873.558000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1963328564 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278873.612000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1963328564 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278873.713000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1963328564 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278873.825000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1963328564 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278876.317000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1928143299 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278876.370000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1928143299 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278876.470000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1928143299 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278876.582000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1928143299 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278877.936000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1254987451 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278877.990000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1254987451 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278878.090000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1254987451 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278878.202000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1254987451 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278878.609000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -755199852 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278878.663000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -755199852 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278878.763000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -755199852 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278878.877000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -755199852 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278879.928000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -568886021 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278879.982000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -568886021 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278880.082000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -568886021 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278880.196000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -568886021 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278881.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1240063810 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278881.979000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1240063810 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278882.078000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1240063810 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278882.193000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1240063810 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278883.928000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1061529248 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278883.981000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1061529248 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278884.081000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1061529248 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278884.194000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1061529248 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278885.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 209456711 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278885.973000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 209456711 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278886.073000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 209456711 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278886.186000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 209456711 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278887.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 415325080 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278887.974000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 415325080 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278888.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 415325080 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278888.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 415325080 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278889.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -797442469 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278889.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -797442469 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278890.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -797442469 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278890.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -797442469 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278891.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -545180830 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278891.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -545180830 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278892.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -545180830 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278892.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -545180830 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278893.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 595306029 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278893.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 595306029 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278894.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 595306029 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278894.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 595306029 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278895.924000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -631655884 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278895.978000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -631655884 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278896.079000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -631655884 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278896.191000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -631655884 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278897.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1096585940 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278897.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1096585940 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278898.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1096585940 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278898.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1096585940 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278899.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1197186288 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278899.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1197186288 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278900.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1197186288 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278900.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1197186288 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278901.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1068730569 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278901.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1068730569 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278902.075000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1068730569 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278902.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1068730569 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278903.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1290028030 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278903.972000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1290028030 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278904.073000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1290028030 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278904.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1290028030 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278905.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 888921772 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278905.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 888921772 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278906.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 888921772 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278906.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 888921772 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278907.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 385846462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278907.973000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 385846462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278908.072000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 385846462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278908.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 385846462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278909.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1344483650 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278909.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1344483650 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278910.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1344483650 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278910.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1344483650 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278911.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1706543636 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278911.973000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1706543636 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278912.072000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1706543636 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278912.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1706543636 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278913.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 140282931 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278913.974000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 140282931 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278914.075000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 140282931 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278914.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 140282931 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278915.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -661154220 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278915.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -661154220 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278916.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -661154220 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278916.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -661154220 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278917.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1467831633 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278917.972000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1467831633 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278918.072000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1467831633 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278918.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1467831633 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278919.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2138311483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278919.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2138311483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278920.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -2138311483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278920.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2138311483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278921.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 89525941 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278921.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 89525941 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278922.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 89525941 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278922.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 89525941 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278923.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 2125554706 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278923.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 2125554706 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278924.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 2125554706 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278924.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 2125554706 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278925.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1526828944 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278925.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1526828944 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278926.078000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1526828944 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278926.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1526828944 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278927.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 21936102 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278927.972000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 21936102 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278928.073000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 21936102 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278928.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 21936102 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278929.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1978981663 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278929.974000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1978981663 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278930.073000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1978981663 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278930.186000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1978981663 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278931.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1673126869 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278931.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1673126869 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278932.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1673126869 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278932.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1673126869 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278933.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1815795963 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278933.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1815795963 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278934.075000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1815795963 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278934.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1815795963 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278935.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -910914134 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278935.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -910914134 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278936.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -910914134 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278936.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -910914134 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278937.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1993253417 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278937.978000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1993253417 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278938.078000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1993253417 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278938.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1993253417 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278939.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1040717625 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278939.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1040717625 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278940.075000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1040717625 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278940.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1040717625 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278941.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 478839984 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278941.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 478839984 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278942.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 478839984 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278942.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 478839984 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278943.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1633779462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278943.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1633779462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278944.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1633779462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278944.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1633779462 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278945.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -205695088 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278945.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -205695088 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278946.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -205695088 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278946.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -205695088 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278947.926000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 478510002 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278947.980000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 478510002 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278948.079000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 478510002 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278948.192000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 478510002 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278949.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -560218168 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278949.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -560218168 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278950.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -560218168 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278950.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -560218168 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278951.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1812369485 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278951.974000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1812369485 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278952.073000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1812369485 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278952.186000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1812369485 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278953.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1095753763 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278953.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1095753763 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278954.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1095753763 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278954.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1095753763 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278955.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1626355916 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278955.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1626355916 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278956.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1626355916 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278956.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1626355916 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278957.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1209415375 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278957.973000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1209415375 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278958.072000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1209415375 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278958.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1209415375 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278959.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -850955712 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278959.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -850955712 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278960.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -850955712 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278960.190000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -850955712 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278961.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1468909939 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278961.977000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1468909939 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278962.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1468909939 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278962.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1468909939 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278963.921000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -876107173 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278963.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -876107173 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278964.075000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -876107173 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278964.187000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -876107173 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278965.923000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2064973483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278965.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2064973483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278966.077000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -2064973483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278966.189000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2064973483 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278967.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -283570526 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278967.972000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -283570526 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278968.072000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -283570526 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278968.184000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -283570526 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278969.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1841965510 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278969.971000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1841965510 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278970.073000 -s 3 -d 1 -i 1841965510 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278970.185000 -s 3 -d 2 -i 1841965510 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278971.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -108132519 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278971.972000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -108132519 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278972.071000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -108132519 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278972.183000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -108132519 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278973.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1156365847 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278973.975000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1156365847 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278974.075000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -1156365847 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278974.186000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -1156365847 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278975.920000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2135535334 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278975.973000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2135535334 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278976.074000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -2135535334 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278976.186000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -2135535334 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
+ -t 1566278977.922000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -945762044 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
- -t 1566278977.976000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -945762044 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
d -t 1566278978.076000 -s 3 -d 1 -i -945762044 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null} -y NOT_DETECTED
r -t 1566278978.188000 -s 3 -d 2 -i -945762044 -p 1 -x {3.0 2.2 -1 ------- null}
# STATS: q=63, t=63, r=63, d=0, O=0.089, L=0.089, D=0.094, T=0.089
# END SIMULATION 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending frames from node 3 to node 2 every 2 seconds. Your simulation runs for 2 minutes, and node 3 continually transmits during that period. Node 2 continually receives. Given that the modems are half-duplex, node 2 is mostly busy receiving, and therefore doesn't get much of a chance to transmit. The exact behavior will depend on the MAC and link being used, as the MAC may backoff for a short while if the PHY is busy receiving a frame when it tries to relay the earlier frame. Given that everything works well when you set the delay to 10 seconds, that this seems to be the most likely explanation.

You can try slowing increasing the delay to check. You can also try setting `link.mac` to `none` to see if that changes the behavior. When the MAC is not set, node 2 will try to relay each frame as soon as the frame is received, as long as it has enough time before the next frame arrives.